# Container build fails on Windows Server 2019 with message 'The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "..." returned a non-zero code: 4294967295'

Tags: docker, .net-core, windows-container

I'm attempting to build a container on a build server on Windows Server 2019, however it keeps failing at the dotnet restore step with the message 'The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "..." returned a non-zero code: 4294967295'. I have been running this manually on the build server while troubleshooting in case there are any issues with the pipeline, but it still fails with the same error.

If anyone is wondering, we are using windows containers/build servers as that is a requirement coming from our IT team.

I'm using the dockerfile generated by visual studio. The build works fine locally when I have docker desktop set to run windows containers. Including it below (i've simplified some of the file paths)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/myService.API.csproj", "Services/myService.API/"]
COPY ["Services/myService.DAL.csproj", "Services/myService.DAL/"]
COPY ["BuildingBlocks/BuildingBlocks.csproj", "BuildingBlocks/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services/myService.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/myService.API"
RUN dotnet build "myService.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myService.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myService.API.dll"]
```

I see a lot of the issues with this error code seem to be connected to WSL and hyper-v, so I confirmed both are installed, however since we are using windows images I am not sure why that would be needed here.

Has anyone encountered this or have any ideas as to what might be causing the issue?

Steps I've taken so far:

1. Initially attempted to build the container through an azure devops pipeline - build failed with the above error message
2. Attempted manually running the build through powershell on the server - same error
3. Attempted building image on my local machine through docker desktop - this works correctly
4. Installed WSL and confirmed the windows container installation and tried re-running - same error

Comment: Can you please provide the details on the error? (Copy/paste the whole thing?) It seems there's something that Docker Build is looking for in the environment that is not present in the build server.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this is a DotNet core app (and I'm not a developer), but is there anything you have to specify on your VC project to let it know it will build on a Windows image?

Comment: Yes this is a dotnet core app.  Unfortunately that is the full error message, the only thing I took out was the specific filepath.  I am aware of this setting in the .csproj file  
`<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Windows</DockerDefaultTargetOS>`  
but I did confirm that is set correctly.  I do wonder if there is somewhere else that it needs to get updated, but I haven't been able to find anything so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be resolved now. We upgraded to Windows Server 2022 and re-installed docker and the build is now succeeding.